# Increase the bitrate tolerance of ffmpeg for creating screenshots of a movie

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm getting the error `bitrate tolerance too small for bitrate` so far no problem. I know that there are several switches to increase that but nothing works.

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/30 -b:v 999999k -bt 999999k -maxrate 999999k -i in.flv out%03d.jpg
```

The source of that commandline is [directly from ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video). But that crashes:

```
ffmpeg version N-44123-g5d55830 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep  2 2012 20:23:29 with gcc 4.7.1 (GCC)
  [...]
Input #0, flv, from 'in.flv':
  Duration: 00:05:00.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 259 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 320x240, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: nellymoser, 22050 Hz, mono, s16
[mjpeg @ 04356860] bitrate tolerance too small for bitrate
[mjpeg @ 04317540] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed
Output #0, image2, to 'out%03d.jpg':
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 0.03 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flv -> mjpeg)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Some ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Though not obviously the problem, it's worth pointing out that order matters with FFmpeg switches: `ffmpeg -r 1/30 -i in.flv out%03d.jpg` is not the same as `ffmepg -i in.flv -r 1/30 out%03d.jpg`, and the second is what you want.

Comment: @rekire Can you provide a link to the input file?

Comment: That was more then two years ago. So no I cannot upload it anymore.